# detect width change in a div and trigger a function Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, dom, knockout.js, oracle-jet

How do I **detect when the width of a div with id X changes**? I have a function 'wrapLines' which **needs to be called whenever this div container's width changes**. because of following reasons

1. whether the window got resized
2. or any other reason like a collapsible menu opening up causing x div to decrease in width

Application uses **Knockout JS** and OJET(Oracle JET). so there is view and viewModel defined for html and respective js.
Please help.

I tried to use window.resize like mentioned below but it doesn't work-

```
$("#" + x).on('resize', function(event) {
    //call wrapLines function         
});
```

The code below works but only for case 1. I need case 2 to pass.

```
$(window).on('resize', function(event) {
   //call wrapLines function               
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`ResizeObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) API.

```js
const elem = document.getElementById("element");
let prevWidth;
new ResizeObserver(([change]) => {
  if ((prevWidth = change.contentRect.width) == prevWidth) {
    console.log(prevWidth);
  }
}).observe(elem);
```

```css
#element {
   resize: horizontal;
   overflow: hidden;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="element">I can be resized!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used the ResizeObserver to create a KnockoutJS binding handler to deal with change events and update an observable with the new width.  Please see
jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/martlark/L03wtzqb/36/

HTML:

```
<textarea id="element" data-bind="resizeWidth: width, value: value"></textarea>
<h4>
Width
</h4>
<span data-bind="text: width"></span>
```

Binding handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.resizeWidth = {
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
    const value = valueAccessor();

    new ResizeObserver(([change]) => {
        value(change.contentRect.width);
    }).observe(element);
  }
};
```

View controller:

```
class ViewModel {
  constructor() {
    this.value = ko.observable('something');
    this.width = ko.observable(0);
    this.width.subscribe(newValue=>{console.log('resize', newValue)})
  }
}

viewModel = new ViewModel()
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```